# Drupal 7: You must include at least one positive keyword with 3 characters or more

Tags: php, drupal-7

I move My drupal 7 website to new server. now for search result i see this error:

```
You must include at least one positive keyword with 3 characters or more.
```

I Run reindex search module and set cron in my setting page. but drupal search not work for me.

how do i can fix this problem?

```
NOTE: before and in old server search worked perfectly 100%.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. go to admin - configuration - search settings, set "Minimum word length to index" 2 or 1
2. on the same page, "re-index" your site. you can go to cron page to run the cron manually immediately, you may also wait for it to run if you are sure the cron is properly set.
   Once the re-index is finished, you can search 2 characters. Before the site is indexed, search does not work.

Comment: I am having this same problem. I did re-index my site and run cron and set the min word length to 1 and still get error: You must include one positive keyword with 1 character or more. This advice did not help, does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when searching from a "Custom Search Block" on the front page of my drupal-site. To resolve it i made an uninstall of "Custom Search 7.x-1.14" and installed "Custom Search 7.x-1.13". (I had some issues with the uninstall, and eventually replaced the files manually in the module-folder "sites/all/modules/custom_search".)

After downgrading to 7.x-1.13 and re-creating my "custom search block", the search now works for me again. I don't know if it was the downgrade, or the re-creation of my custom search block that fixed my problem..

Answer (score 0):

See if this error exists in Reports (Drupal 6)

**preg_replace(): Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 1816 in core module search/search.module on line 335.**

Then delete **"x{d800}-\x{f8ff}\"** from **PREG_CLASS_SEARCH_EXCLUDE** definition in *search/search.module*.

Clear cache. Search should work!!

works for me.